# WPF MVVM Pagination

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, pagination

I have a user control for pagination view, it has its own viewmodel. I added the pagination in a page with a datagrid that also has a separate viewmodel.

My question is how can I update the ObservableCollection I have in my page viewmodel every time a command is done in my pagination viewmodel?

Here's my PagingControl.xaml

```
<StackPanel Width="Auto"
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button                
            Margin="4,0"
            Content="&lt;&lt;"
            Command="{Binding FirstCommand}"/>
        <Button
            Margin="4,0"
            Content="&lt;"
            Command="{Binding PreviousCommand}"/>
        <StackPanel
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Start}"/>
            <TextBlock
                Text=" to "/>
            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding End}"/>
            <TextBlock
                Text=" of "/>
            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding TotalItems}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button
            Margin="4,0"
            Content="&gt;"
            Command="{Binding NextCommand}"/>
        <Button
            Margin="4,0"
            Content="&gt;&gt;"
            Command="{Binding LastCommand}"/>
        <ComboBox Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsPerPage}" SelectedValue="{Binding ItemCount}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CountChangedCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

PagingViewModel.cs

```
public class PagingViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<DataModel> _data;

    private int start = 0;
    private int itemCount = 10;
    private int totalItems = 0;
    private readonly List<int> count;

    private ICommand _firstCommand;
    private ICommand _previousCommand;
    private ICommand _nextCommand;
    private ICommand _lastCommand;
    private ICommand _countchangedCommand;

    public ObservableCollection<DataModel> Data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set
        {
            if (_data!= value)
            {
                _data= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Data");
            }
        }
    }

    public PagingViewModel()
    {
        count = new List<int> { 10, 20, 30};
        RefreshData();
    }

    public int Start { get { return start + 1; } }

    public int End { get { return start + itemCount < totalItems ? start + itemCount : totalItems; } }

    public int TotalItems { get { return totalItems; } }

    public List<int> Count { get { return count; } }

    public int ItemCount { get { return itemCount; } set { itemCount = value; OnPropertyChanged("ItemCount"); } }

    public ICommand FirstCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_firstCommand == null)
            {
                _firstCommand = new RelayCommand
                (
                    param =>
                    {
                        start = 0;
                        RefreshData();
                    },
                    param =>
                    {
                        return start - itemCount >= 0 ? true : false;
                    }
                );
            }

            return _firstCommand;
        }
    }

    public ICommand PreviousCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_previousCommand == null)
            {
                _previousCommand = new RelayCommand
                (
                    param =>
                    {
                        start -= itemCount;
                        RefreshData();
                    },
                    param =>
                    {
                        return start - itemCount >= 0 ? true : false;
                    }
                );
            }

            return _previousCommand;
        }
    }

    public ICommand NextCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_nextCommand == null)
            {
                _nextCommand = new RelayCommand
                (
                    param =>
                    {
                        start += itemCount;
                        RefreshData();
                    },
                    param =>
                    {
                        return start + itemCount < totalItems ? true : false;
                    }
                );
            }

            return _nextCommand;
        }
    }

    public ICommand LastCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_lastCommand == null)
            {
                _lastCommand = new RelayCommand
                (
                    param =>
                    {
                        start = (totalItems / itemCount - 1) * itemCount;
                        start += totalItems % itemCount == 0 ? 0 : itemCount;
                        RefreshData();
                    },
                    param =>
                    {
                        return start + itemCount < totalItems ? true : false;
                    }
                );
            }

            return _lastCommand;
        }
    }

    public ICommand CountChangedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_countchangedCommand == null)
            {
                _countchangedCommand = new RelayCommand
                (
                    param =>
                    {
                        start = 0;
                        RefreshData();
                    },
                    param =>
                    {
                        return ((totalItems - itemCount) > -10) ? true : false;
                    }
                );
            }

            return _countchangedCommand;
        }
    }

    public void RefreshData()
    {
        _data= GetData(start, itemCount, out totalItems);
DataViewModel vm = new DataViewModel(this);

        OnPropertyChanged("Start");
        OnPropertyChanged("End");
        OnPropertyChanged("TotalItems");
    }
}
```

And here's the viewmodel for my Page: DataViewModel.cs

```
public class DataViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<DataModel> _data;

    public ObservableCollection<DataModel> Data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set
        {
            if (_data!= value)
            {
                _data= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Data");
            }
        }
    }

    public DataViewModel(PagingViewModel pagevm)
    {
        _data = new ObservableCollection<DataModel>();
        _data= pagevm.Data; 
    }

}
```

My Data property is bound to an ItemSource of a DataGrid in DataView.xaml with DataContext set to DataViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

That's a nicely detailled question !

For your refresh problems i see a few options : 
When setting your *Data* in *RefreshData* you should use the public setter of the property and not *_data*. If you don't you will never use the OnPropertyChanged to notify the view that your whole collection changed.

So you need to replace :

```
_data= GetData(start, itemCount, out totalItems);
```

With :

```
Data= GetData(start, itemCount, out totalItems);
```

By the way your DataViewModel makes no sense to me. Your  *_audits* field is nowhere to be seen and the *ObservableCollection Data* is never set in this ViewModel. I belive your problem must come from this.

**PS :**

On the other hand i have some advices not directly related to your question:

First of all, when you want to to check if some RelayCommand or else is null before setting it you may want to use the ?? operator : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/ms173224.aspx.

Secondly i **highly** recommand you to put your RelayCommands behaviours in methods. When you end up with dozen of commands it's a real mess to maintain RelayCommand where everything happens in lambdas.

This way you will replace this:

```
public ICommand NextCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_nextCommand == null)
        {
            _nextCommand = new RelayCommand
            (
                param =>
                {
                    start += itemCount;
                    RefreshData();
                },
                param =>
                {
                    return start + itemCount < totalItems ? true : false;
                }
            );
        }
           return _nextCommand;
    }
}
```

With this :

```
 public ICommand NextCommand
 {
     get
     {
         return _nextCommand = _nextCommand ?? new RelayCommand(Next, CanExecuteNext);
     }
 }

 private void Next()
 {
     start += itemCount;
     RefreshData();
 }

 private bool CanExecuteNext()
 {
     return start + itemCount < totalItems ? true : false;
 }
```

Comment: Hi yan yankelevich, my bad on the AuditTrail part. It's supposed to be the constructor for the DataViewModel, I already edited it and will try your answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: I implemented your answer but my problem now I can't seem to update my DataGrid in which Data is bounded. The values are already pass but the datagrid aren't updating based on new values of Observable Collection :(

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your commands need to be able to access your page view model. For them to do this your paging viewModel would need to hold a reference to the page viewModel (so that your paging viewModel could pass this to the relevant command).

I suggest using property injection. In your PagingViewModel add a property like this;

```
    public AuditTrailViewModel AuditTrailViewModel { get; set; }
```

(Give the property change notification if you need to).

In your commands you would now be able to access the properties of the AuditTrailViewModel

```
public ICommand LastCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_lastCommand == null)
        {
            _lastCommand = new RelayCommand
            (
                param =>
                {
                    start = (totalItems / itemCount - 1) * itemCount;
                    start += totalItems % itemCount == 0 ? 0 : itemCount;
                    AuditTrailViewModel.Data = //Now you can update your viewModel
                    RefreshData();
                },
                param =>
                {
                    return start + itemCount < totalItems ? true : false;
                }
            );
        }

        return _lastCommand;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi mark_h, my bad on the AuditTrail part. It's supposed to be the constructor for the DataViewModel, I already edited it and will try your answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: Tried your anser and gives me an 'OBject not set to an instance' error in this line >> `AuditTrailViewModel.Data = //Now you can update your viewModel`.